# How to delete a record from a jcombobox after using the record in another file? (java)

Tags: java

For my current java project we are making a school application that lets supervisors be assigned to certain activities.

My activity file looks like this:
ID, Activity Name, Supervisor ID, Location, Time
My supervisor file looks like this:
Name, Specialization, EmailID, UUID

The supervisor ID and name are excerpted from supervisors file and placed in a JComboBox.

I need to remove the supervisor name and ID from the ComboBox after it has been assigned to an activity.

Thank you!

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  The [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) section explains how to use combo boxes.

Comment: Read the JComboBox API. There are various `remove???(...)` methods that allow you to remove an item from the combo box.